# Sequelize Many to Many realtionship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize, and I have two models, with many to many relationships, the employees model it has RegistrationNmuber as Primary Key , firstName, LastName amongst other information,  and a message model it has an id attribute, from attribute which is the RegistrationNumber of the employee, and the  to attribute contain the another RegistrationNumber of another employee, and 
 message attribute, 
what I want to do is find the information of employee from the 'from  attribute of message model', is it possible to do it and how?? if not can anybody please suggest a solution

```
             // employee model:
            module.exports = (sequelize,Sequelize) => {
const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee' ,{

 RegistrationNumber :{
  type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  primaryKey: true
 },
 CIN : {
    type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
    unique: true
 },

FirstName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,

},
LastName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING

},
image:{
  type: Sequelize.BLOB
},
 DateofBirth: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,

},
PlaceOfBirth: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,

},
Address: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT,

},
Email: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  unique: true

},
PhoneNumber: {
  type: Sequelize.BIGINT,

},
DateofNamingRank :{
 type: Sequelize.DATE
},
DateofDesignationAdministration :{
  type: Sequelize.DATE
 },
 Type :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 DateofDemarcation :{
  type: Sequelize.DATE
 },
 Item :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Rank :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Case :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Position :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 ActualWork :{
  type:Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Wire :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Plan :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Specialization :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Intrest :{
  type: Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Role :{
   type:Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Login:{
   type:Sequelize.STRING
 },
 Password :{
   type:Sequelize.STRING
 }
    }, 
    );  return Employee;
     }

     // message Model
        module.exports =( sequelize,Sequelize)=>{
const Messages = sequelize.define('Messages' ,{

    id :{
        type:  Sequelize.BIGINT,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    from :{
        type : Sequelize.BIGINT
    },
    to :{
        type : Sequelize.BIGINT  
    } ,
    message:{
       type: Sequelize.TEXT   
    }
})
return Messages;
```

}

```
                 // Relation
                db.employee.belongsToMany(db.messages,{
               through : "employee_Messages",
                } )
                db.messages.belongsToMany(db.employee , 
                 {through:"employee_Messages"})
```

Comment: Yes you can achieve it if you have all the required relationships in place and configured the mappings within the models correctly. Can you post how the tables contents and how they are mapped and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess you want to get employee information when you pass in message Id.

Comment: how can I  get the employee information with a message id??

Comment: Can you describe how are you tables mapped? How is message table related to employee table. What are the foreign keys. Do we have a mapping table which holds the relationship between these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.messages.belongsTo(db.employee, {
  foreignKey: "from"
})
db.messages.belongsTo(db.employee, {
  foreignKey: "to"
})

messages.find({
  where: {
    id: messageId
  },
  include: [{
      model: employee,
      as: from,
      required: true
    },
    {
      model: employee,
      as: to,
      required: true
    }
  ]
}).then(message => {
const userfrom = message.from;
const userto = message.to;
})
```

I guess this helps.

Comment: I think my configuration is wrong, can you take look and fixed to me??

Comment: It looks like a user is mapped to multiple messages. This looks like 1:m mapping not a m:m. RegistrationNumber is foriegn key in messages table for from and to columns. let me know if that's correct assumption. And you want to find users if you pass a messages Id

Comment: I really don't know what I want, I just want send messages between users, i

Comment: I get :  ReferenceError: from is not defined

Comment: try to change: as: 'from' 
Change it to string.

Comment: If you need help you can ping me on LinkedIn(link on my profile) or Gmail. My id is the same as my GitHub or Twitter one.